# foward referencing types in java

Tags: java, compiler-construction, typechecking

In java, you can't do this

```
Object x = y;
Object y = null;
```

But you **can** do this:

```
class A { B bref = null; }
class B {}
```

Why is this the case? 
Can anyone explain  how, in the second case, the compiler know about `B`?

Comment: You can ask the same question about a linked-list-like structure `class A {A aref = null;}`.

Answer (score 1):

In first block:

```
Object x = y;
Object y = null;
```

You first declare `x` to be equal to `y`, this will only compile if and only if `y` has been declared.
In the second line you declare `Object y` to be `null`, tis will only compile if `y` has not been declared before.

Therefore, your first statement can never compile and makes no sense.

Now onto the second block:

```
class A { B bref = null; }
class B {}
```

Here you create, a package private class `A`, which has as package private member a variable of class `B` (whatever `B` may be, as long as `B` is present in the source files), that is `null` upon initialization. The class also has a public constructor that does nothing essential.
Then you create, a package private class `B`, which only has the public constructor.

You do nothing else in your code, and everything is completely valid Java.

You can do what you are doing, because it is all valid Java syntax.
Moreover, the compiler knows about `B`, because it first **compiles** your files, and therefore all classes are present and known.

Answer (score -1):

In the first case, you didn't declare the reference y before x. Because of this, the compiler doesn't know what y represents. In the second case, you have a reference of type B to null so it's ok. If you wouldn't have put null, it will still be the same since instance member objects are set by default to null. This is an example of composition.

Comment: No, that is wrong. When the compiler typechecks the `A` declaration block, it will see `B` as a newtype, which it hasn't known about. It doesn't matter what I set it to.

Comment: That can't be, this is an example of code that compiles ok:  `code`public class TestClass {
}

class A{ B  ref = null;}
class B{}`code`

Comment: I didn't say that  the code wasn't gonna compile. What I said was that your explanation is wrong.

Comment: I think I understand what you say. I think that at compile type, all the classes that are included in the classpath are checked using the fully qualified name so no class naming collision will occur. If you have no imports and the classes are in the same java file they should be recognized, just like inner classes are.